# telnet localhost connection refused but connect with local ip

Tags: telnet

I have an application that is supposed to connect to localhost:9000. But it fails. 
Telnet gives me:

telnet localhost 9000

```
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.111...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'
```

So when I changed my application config and set it up to connect to 192.168.0.111:9000 then it works.

What is wrong?

Comment: The server doesn't listen on the wild-card address, but is bound to a specific address?

Comment: You tell the server to listen to `INADDR_ANY` (if you're programming the server) or by reading what options/configuration it needs to listen to all interfaces (if it's not your server).

Answer (score 0):

Likely in your configuration file you have commented out the localhost IP 127.0.0.7 but have the IP for the external service listed.  If you are running sendmail look in the config file.